# Is there a way to run an action immediately upon executing the installer?

Tags: install4j

I have an application whose installer is built with Install4J and when I run the Windows installer exe file the GUI doesn't appear until after about 15 seconds. During this time, there's an empty console visible to the user, and they may get the impression that nothing is happening.

What I'd like to do is simply print a message to the user, so they know the installer is running prior to the GUI appearing (or some other solution with a similar effect).

I added an action to the "Startup" section of the Install4j config that prints a message to the console. As far as I can tell, this is the earliest I can configure Install4J to do an action. It works great except that it doesn't print until after the GUI has already loaded, which defeats the purpose. It's currently the only action in the "Startup" section - moving our other startup actions to happen later didn't have any effect on how soon the message is displayed.

In the i4j_nlog_1 log file, it says what was happening during those 15 seconds before the GUI appears. ~5.5 seconds are verifying integrity, and ~7.2 seconds are extracting/creating. Ideally, I'd be able to print a hello message prior to any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, installj4 immediately shows a native progress dialog when the installer is executed.

It is possible to deactivate that progress dialog by deselecting the "Suppress initial progress dialog" property on the "Installer" node in the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step.